# np.Nan value in parquet table

Tags: python, pandas, apache, numpy, parquet

I have a pandas data frame with all columns being strings and one column is an integer. I would like to convert this data frame to the parquet table.

But the problem here is, the integer column in pandas Dataframe is considered as Float by pandas because of np.nan but I would like to save this column as an integer column in parquet table. When I tried this, parquet is throwing an error saying Floating point value truncated and the conversion failed for that column.

I thought of filling this na values to some default value but it's not accepted because of some other factors.

Overall, My goal here is to save np.nan values in parquet table.

Feel free to ask me for more info. I am happy to explain.

Comment: https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/details.html#nulls

Comment: when I creating a table from data, has_nulls option isn't working